# Inserting element into linked list while traversing C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, shared-ptr, traversal

I'm new to C++ and having some difficultly with the use of shared ptrs. I've been able to construct a linked list. I want to traverse the linked list, and when the nodes (elements) have a valid to_add field, to add the element into the list, and continue.

```
class Element{
public:
    char el = 'Z';
    std::shared_ptr<Element> next;
    char to_add = 'Z';
    Element(char input){
        el = input;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};
```

^ structure of node. I'm looking at the to_add field to see if there's an element to add in.

```
class Polymer{
public:
    std::vector<Instruction> instruction;
    std::shared_ptr<Element> extract_and_store_input(std::ifstream &file);
    void prepare_insertion(std::shared_ptr<Element> head);
    void insert_elements(std::shared_ptr<Element> head);
    Polymer(std::ifstream &file){
        std::shared_ptr<Element> head = extract_and_store_input(file);
        prepare_insertion(head);
        insert_elements(head);

    }
};
```

^ calling code format

v problem is somewhere here

```
std::shared_ptr<Element> add_element(std::shared_ptr<Element> head_cpy){
    auto tmp = head_cpy->next;
    head_cpy->next = std::make_shared<Element>(head_cpy->to_add);
    head_cpy->next = tmp;
    return tmp;
}


void Polymer::insert_elements(std::shared_ptr<Element> head) {

    auto trav = head;
    auto tmp= head;

    // for (int i = 0; i < num_steps; i ++)
    while (trav->next != nullptr) {
        std::cout<<trav->el<<std::endl;
        if (trav->to_add != 'Z'){
            std::cout<<"adding"<<trav->to_add<<std::endl;
            trav=add_element(trav);
            trav=trav->next; // progress forward twice
        }
        trav=trav->next;
    }

//    while (tmp->el != 'Z'){
//        std::cout<<tmp->el<<std::endl;
//        tmp=tmp->next;
//    }


}
```

I think that the issue may be that the pointer doing the traversal (trav) is updating the list itself, rather than progressing through the list? I would really appreciate any insights!

If anyone recognises the q, it's from AoC day 14 :) I'm sure there are better ways to do it, but I'd like to understand the problem here first!

Comment: You want to traverse a linked list to look for elements which you can insert into the linked list? Sorry that confuses me. Is there more than one linked list? Please read [ask] and make a [mre].

Comment: I want to traverse a linked list, and when there is an element to add (the to_add field != 'Z'), add it, and continue.

Comment: Please rephrase instead of repeating the phrasing which confused me. Are there two lists? If you found an element in a linked list it obviously already has been added to the list. So what list do you intend to add it to?

Comment: There is one linked list. Within each node, there is a field 'to_add', which means that this needs to be added into the list. It hasn't yet been added, but I need to traverse the list to find the elements where this field is valid, so that I can add it, and continue traversing.

Comment: So you traverse a linked list. Each node you encounter you check for a condition. If that is met you want to add the node which you found inside the linked list to the linked list. Which means it will now be twice insider the linked list. Also, depending on where in the list you add it you might encouinter it immediatly again, do you then wnat to add it again? Please descriobe the purpose and goal of what you are trying to do.

Comment: "It hasn't yet been added" Then where do you find it while traversing the only existing list?

Comment: it is within a different field of the node. e.g. element1.el = A, element1.to_add = B, element2.el = C, is a list A->C and needs to become A->B->C

Comment: It's probably just me, not getting the whole idea of this. I am sure others find your explanations perfectly clear and won't need a [mre] or a question according to [ask]. Good luck.

Comment: I found the problem statement here:  https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/14

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.